# "Linking" Nest Dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm fairly new to programming, so please bear with me. I've been working on a project and am learning a huge about amount dicts and lists. I'm near the end, but have been stuck on a particular portion for a week now and could use some help.

I have a dict and a list, both with nested dicts of a large amount of data. I will provide samples:

**neo_dict** (these are only the first three nested dicts of about 40,000):

```
    {
    "2020 M3": {
        "id": "dK20M030",
        "spkid": "1003699",
        "full_name": "     C/2020 M3 (ATLAS)",
        "pdes": "2020 M3",
        "name": "ATLAS",
        "prefix": "C",
        "neo": "Y",
        "pha": "",
        "H": "",
        "G": "",
        "M1": "14.6",
        "M2": "",
        "K1": "6.5",
        "K2": "",
        "PC": "",
        "diameter": "",
        "extent": "",
        "albedo": "",
        "rot_per": "",
        "GM": "",
        "BV": "",
        "UB": "",
        "IR": "",
        "spec_B": "",
        "spec_T": "",
        "H_sigma": "",
        "diameter_sigma": "",
        "orbit_id": "JPL 17",
        "epoch": "2459177.5",
        "epoch_mjd": "59177",
        "epoch_cal": "20201124",
        "equinox": "J2000",
        "e": "0.952708189",
        "a": "26.81750256",
        "q": "1.26824827",
        "i": "23.47352818",
        "om": "71.2502355",
        "w": "328.4462512",
        "ma": "0.208483561",
        "ad": "52.36675686",
        "n": "0.007097029",
        "tp": "2459148.124",
        "tp_cal": "20201025.62",
        "per": "50725.45171",
        "per_y": "138.8787179",
        "moid": "0.327377",
        "moid_ld": "127.4053071",
        "moid_jup": "0.886293",
        "t_jup": "1.46",
        "sigma_e": "2.52E-06",
        "sigma_a": "0.0014408",
        "sigma_q": "5.38E-07",
        "sigma_i": "2.93E-05",
        "sigma_om": "9.94E-06",
        "sigma_w": "1.70E-05",
        "sigma_ma": "1.68E-05",
        "sigma_ad": "0.0028134",
        "sigma_n": "5.72E-07",
        "sigma_tp": "1.88E-05",
        "sigma_per": "4.0879",
        "class": "HTC",
        "producer": "Otto Matic",
        "data_arc": "265",
        "first_obs": "6/27/2020",
        "last_obs": "3/19/2021",
        "n_obs_used": "2140",
        "n_del_obs_used": "",
        "n_dop_obs_used": "",
        "condition_code": "3",
        "rms": "0.48834",
        "two_body": "",
        "A1": "",
        "A2": "",
        "A3": "",
        "DT": ""
    },
    "2020 P4-B": {
        "id": "dK20P04b",
        "spkid": "1003715",
        "full_name": "     C/2020 P4-B",
        "pdes": "2020 P4-B",
        "name": "",
        "prefix": "C",
        "neo": "Y",
        "pha": "",
        "H": "",
        "G": "",
        "M1": "16.2",
        "M2": "",
        "K1": "10",
        "K2": "",
        "PC": "",
        "diameter": "",
        "extent": "",
        "albedo": "",
        "rot_per": "",
        "GM": "",
        "BV": "",
        "UB": "",
        "IR": "",
        "spec_B": "",
        "spec_T": "",
        "H_sigma": "",
        "diameter_sigma": "",
        "orbit_id": "JPL 1",
        "epoch": "2459068.5",
        "epoch_mjd": "59068",
        "epoch_cal": "20200807",
        "equinox": "J2000",
        "e": "0.909209182",
        "a": "1.020070968",
        "q": "0.092613078",
        "i": "28.14731293",
        "om": "173.4267944",
        "w": "171.6064847",
        "ma": "358.9621325",
        "ad": "1.947528857",
        "n": "0.956661933",
        "tp": "2459069.585",
        "tp_cal": "20200808.08",
        "per": "376.3084822",
        "per_y": "1.030276474",
        "moid": "0.135011",
        "moid_ld": "52.54223087",
        "moid_jup": "3.49537",
        "t_jup": "5.426",
        "sigma_e": "0.16589",
        "sigma_a": "1.9184",
        "sigma_q": "0.031723",
        "sigma_i": "4.689",
        "sigma_om": "14.935",
        "sigma_w": "29.714",
        "sigma_ma": "2.8976",
        "sigma_ad": "3.6627",
        "sigma_n": "2.6988",
        "sigma_tp": "0.6924",
        "sigma_per": "1061.6",
        "class": "ETc",
        "producer": "Davide Farnocchia",
        "data_arc": "1",
        "first_obs": "8/6/2020",
        "last_obs": "8/7/2020",
        "n_obs_used": "80",
        "n_del_obs_used": "",
        "n_dop_obs_used": "",
        "condition_code": "9",
        "rms": "0.079265",
        "two_body": "",
        "A1": "",
        "A2": "",
        "A3": "",
        "DT": ""
    },
    "2020 P4-C": {
        "id": "dK20P04c",
        "spkid": "1003716",
        "full_name": "     C/2020 P4-C",
        "pdes": "2020 P4-C",
        "name": "",
        "prefix": "C",
        "neo": "Y",
        "pha": "",
        "H": "",
        "G": "",
        "M1": "15.6",
        "M2": "",
        "K1": "10",
        "K2": "",
        "PC": "",
        "diameter": "",
        "extent": "",
        "albedo": "",
        "rot_per": "",
        "GM": "",
        "BV": "",
        "UB": "",
        "IR": "",
        "spec_B": "",
        "spec_T": "",
        "H_sigma": "",
        "diameter_sigma": "",
        "orbit_id": "JPL 1",
        "epoch": "2459069.5",
        "epoch_mjd": "59069",
        "epoch_cal": "20200808",
        "equinox": "J2000",
        "e": "0.939420568",
        "a": "1.390541481",
        "q": "0.084238213",
        "i": "37.55936253",
        "om": "165.2569181",
        "w": "116.4217142",
        "ma": "0.699590126",
        "ad": "2.69684475",
        "n": "0.601074288",
        "tp": "2459068.336",
        "tp_cal": "20200806.84",
        "per": "598.927632",
        "per_y": "1.639774489",
        "moid": "0.335478",
        "moid_ld": "130.5579733",
        "moid_jup": "3.29387",
        "t_jup": "4.023",
        "sigma_e": "5.0775",
        "sigma_a": "113.92",
        "sigma_q": "0.28571",
        "sigma_i": "93.792",
        "sigma_om": "70.845",
        "sigma_w": "359.42",
        "sigma_ma": "83.269",
        "sigma_ad": "220.95",
        "sigma_n": "73.867",
        "sigma_tp": "4.8578",
        "sigma_per": "73603",
        "class": "ETc",
        "producer": "Davide Farnocchia",
        "data_arc": "",
        "first_obs": "8/7/2020",
        "last_obs": "8/7/2020",
        "n_obs_used": "29",
        "n_del_obs_used": "",
        "n_dop_obs_used": "",
        "condition_code": "9",
        "rms": "0.024266",
        "two_body": "",
        "A1": "",
        "A2": "",
        "A3": "",
        "DT": ""
    }
}
```

Each nested dict uses the pdes as key.

I also have a list of nested dicts. The first three nested dicts (of about 30,000) within the list are:

**cad_list**

```
[{"des": "2003 JC17", "orbit_id": "18", "jd": "2488068.556306376", "cd": "2099-Dec-31 01:21", "dist": "0.338023789278089", "dist_min": "0.337895151250112", "dist_max": "0.338152711373013", "v_rel": "22.5355709843525", "v_inf": "22.5352212003886", "t_sigma_f": "00:58", "h": "17.8"}
{"des": "2017 WS12", "orbit_id": "7", "jd": "2488068.734163492", "cd": "2099-Dec-31 05:37", "dist": "0.141595130202053", "dist_min": "0.129742488499914", "dist_max": "0.156296976341895", "v_rel": "7.51471164318556", "v_inf": "7.51220712553632", "t_sigma_f": "3_07:42", "h": "23.2"}
{"des": "2010 XB24", "orbit_id": "19", "jd": "2488069.369087819", "cd": "2099-Dec-31 20:51", "dist": "0.126306889299689", "dist_min": "0.125428658725108", "dist_max": "0.127185695415594", "v_rel": "16.6758717193855", "v_inf": "16.6746066532063", "t_sigma_f": "01:03", "h": "21.8"}]
```

What I want to do is create a new dict that holds all of the information from `neo_dict`. Then, if the value in `des` for each nested dict within `cad_list` matches any of the keys within `neo_dict`, I want to add that nested dict from `cad_list` onto the nested dict within `neo_dict`.

So for instance:

**neo_dict**

```
{
"2020 M3": {
    "id": "dK20M030",
    "spkid": "1003699",
    "full_name": "     C/2020 M3 (ATLAS)",}}
```

**cad_list**

```
[{"des": "2020 M3", "orbit_id": "18", "jd": "2488068.556306376"}]
```

**new_dict**

```
{
"2020 M3": {
    "id": "dK20M030",
    "spkid": "1003699",
    "full_name": "     C/2020 M3 (ATLAS)",
    "orbit_id": "18",
    "jd": "2488068.556306376",
 }}
```

I tried to make it as simple as possible. Please let me know if you have any questions.

**

### UPDATE:

**
I am taking it step by step. Right now, I am trying to access the `'des'` key within `cad_list`, but I am getting a TypeError.

`>>> print(cad_list[0]['des'])`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\xxx", line 110, in __init__
    print(cad_list[0]['des'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is go through the values of of your **cad_list**

```
for stuff in cad_list:
```

then check if the "des" is in **neo_dict**

```
if stuff['des'] in neo_dict:
```

Then if it matches you can create a new dict from the info you get. I am not sure how you want this new dict, in a list or another dict so wasn't sure how to code that portion out.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I apologize, as I should have been more specific with what results I would like. I would like them in a dict that looks exactly like `neo_dict`, except the keys and items within `cad_list` should be added onto the `new_dict`. I've been trying for a long time and decided it's time to reach out.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem I was having. When I created `cad_list` by appending each dict item, I appended the dictionary incorrectly (I used json.dumps(cad_dict)). So, when I was trying to access the keys in the dict, the nested dict was actually an str. But, when using the print(cad_dict) function, it printed it out looking like a nested dict.

I ended up using type(cad_dict[0]) which told me it was an str.